# Primeng datatable issue

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have used the p-data table in a loop, inside the table I have used the checkbox field for column. This is displaying well but if you click on the header of first table the second table fields are unchecked.
How can I differentiate the header checkbox field from table to table.

My code is:

```
 <div *ngFor='let selectedDomain of assessmentObj.selectedDomains;let i=index'> 

<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4 m-b-20 m-t-10 customLabel">{{selectedDomain.domainName || 'NA'}}</div> 

<p-dataTable [value]="selectedDomain.controlCategories" [editable]="true" sortField="controlCategory" [responsive]="true" rowGroupMode="rowspan" [(selection)]="selectedArrray" (onRowUnselect)="selectedRows($event,selectedArrray)" (onRowSelect)="selectedRows($event,selectedArrray)" [headerCheckboxToggleAllPages]="true"> 

<p-column field="controlCategory" header="Control Category"></p-column>

<p-column field="isoControl" header="Control Item"></p-column> 
<p-column field="question" header="Questions" [editable]="true">
</p-column> 

<p-column [style]="{'width':'38px'}" selectionMode="multiple"></p-column>
 </p-dataTable> 
</div>
```

Comment: can you post your full code here

Comment: use the dataarray as ngModel

Comment: <p-dataTable [value]="selectedDomain.controlCategories" [editable]="true" sortField="controlCategory" [responsive]="true" rowGroupMode="rowspan" [(selection)]="selectedArrray" (onRowUnselect)="selectedRows($event,selectedArrray)" (onRowSelect)="selectedRows($event,selectedArrray)" [headerCheckboxToggleAllPages]="true">
                    <p-column [style]="{'width':'38px'}" selectionMode="multiple"></p-column>
                  </p-dataTable>

Comment: this table is in loop

Comment: I have to differentiate the header checkbox colum field for every table

Comment: Please help me...

Comment: Please DO NOT post code in comments. Instead edit your question and paste the code in there with proper formatting.

Comment: chek it once please